# org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate entity descriptor: com.game.server.core.entity.BaseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following problem, specifically I have 1 **BaseEntity** declared:

```
package com.game.server.core.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    protected LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public BaseEntity() {
         this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
         this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

     @PreUpdate
     public void preUpdate() {
         this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
     }
 }
```

and Entity class **User** :

```
package com.game.server.core.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class User extends BaseEntity{
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

And here is the **DaoCore** repository :

```
package com.game.server.core.dao;

import com.game.server.core.entity.BaseEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface DaoCore<T extends BaseEntity,ID extends Integer> extends 
JpaRepository<T,ID> {
}
```

And here is the **AbstractServiceCRUD** :

```
package com.game.server.core.base;

import com.game.server.core.dao.DaoCore;
import com.game.server.core.entity.BaseEntity;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;

@Service
@Slf4j(topic = "AbstractServiceCRUD")
@Transactional(rollbackOn = RuntimeException.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AbstractServiceCRUD<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Integer> implements ServiceCore<T, ID> {
    private final DaoCore<T, ID> daoCore;

    @Override
    public T save(T bo) {
        try {
            log.info("saving data");
            return daoCore.save(bo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error saving data", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T bo, ID id) {
        try {
            if (!(id instanceof Integer)) {
                log.info("id is not instance Integer");
                return null;
            }
            boolean isExist = daoCore.existsById(id);
            if (isExist) {
                log.info("updating data with id: {}", id);
                bo.preUpdate();
                return daoCore.save(bo);
            }
            log.info("data with id: {} not found", id);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error updating data", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public T delete(T bo) {
        try {
            ID id = (ID) bo.getId();
            if (id != null) {
                log.info("deleting data with id: {}", id);
                daoCore.deleteById(id);
                return bo;
            }
            log.info("data with id: {} not found", id);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error deleting data", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T findById(ID id) {
        log.info("finding data with id: {}", id);
        T bo = daoCore.findById(id).orElse(null);
        if (bo != null) {
            log.info("data with id: {} found", id);
            return bo;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayDeque<T> findAll() {
        log.info("finding all data");
        return new ArrayDeque<>(daoCore.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.info("finding all data with page {} and size {}", pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize());
        return daoCore.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

and here is **AbstractControllerCRUD** :

```
package com.game.server.core.base;

import com.game.server.core.entity.BaseEntity;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AbstractControllerCRUD<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Integer> implements ServiceCore<T, ID>{
    @Autowired
    private AbstractServiceCRUD<T, ID> abstractServiceCRUD;


    @PostMapping("/insert")
    @Override
    public T save(@RequestBody T bo) {
        return abstractServiceCRUD.save(bo);
    }

    @PostMapping("/update/{id}")
    @Override
    public T update( @RequestBody T bo,@PathVariable ID id) {
        return abstractServiceCRUD.update(bo, id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    @Override
    public T delete(@RequestBody T bo) {
        return abstractServiceCRUD.delete(bo);
    }

    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    @Override
    public T findById(@PathVariable ID id) {
        return abstractServiceCRUD.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAll")
    @Override
    public ArrayDeque<T> findAll() {
        return abstractServiceCRUD.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAllPage")
    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(@RequestBody Pageable pageable) {
        return abstractServiceCRUD.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

And here is **UserController** :

```
package com.game.server.core.endpoint;

import com.game.server.core.base.AbstractControllerCRUD;
import com.game.server.core.entity.User;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController extends AbstractControllerCRUD<User,Integer> {
}
```

and here is **application.properities** file :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nro
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
```

When I call to api : **/api/user/insert** it successfully adds no problem, but when I call to api : **/api/user/find/{id}**
then it will throw the following error: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: ***Unable to locate entity descriptor: com.game.server.core.entity.BaseEntity***,
I have used EntityScan to scan Entities but it is not possible, my purpose is not to want JPA to create a table for BaseEntity

Comment: I would try to remove abstract from "public abstract class BaseEntity".

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: Remove the `DaoCore` since it's not needed. Just use the `JpaRepository` to create proper entity repositories, like the `UserRepository`. If you want to use polymorphic queries, you can do that using custom JPA Repository methods.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much bro <3